# Chrome extension cookies.getAll doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I have made an extension for quick cookies managing. And after changes for manifest v.2 I have some strange bugs.
Here's a part of my code

```
console.log('start');
...
var initer = function(i){
    console.log('get cookies');
    chrome.cookies.getAll({domain:nets[tinuse]['cookies'][i]}, function (f){
        console.log(f);
        ....
    });
}
console.log('get cookies');
chrome.cookies.getAll({domain:nets[tinuse]['cookies'][0]}, function (f){
    console.log(f);
    ....
    initer(i);
});
```

In console I get:

```
start
get cookies

get cookies
```

For the second call I don't get even empty console log message. If i make the same call manually from console for popup window, everything is OK.

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({domain:nets[tinuse]['cookies'][0]}, function (f){
    console.log(f);});
undefined
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, ...]
```

All permissions is OK. These methods called from click event listener, and totally all is OK except getting cookies. And I can't finish process because the second callback (in **initer** body is not fired at all).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have permission to use the cookies APIs. Request for permission to cookies in your extension's manifest like

```
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "cookies"
  ],
  ...
```

Refer to the [Chrome Developer Cookies documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/cookies/).